# JavaScript Function onClick only works once

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, onclick

I have been working on learning JavaScript, and I have a piece of JavaScript which is supposed to open a hamburger menu on the top left of the page.

The thing is, the code works once, but for some reason the if{} statement is not working the second time:

```
let toggleNavStatus = false;

let toggleNav = function() {


    let getSidebar = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar");
    let getSidebarUl = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar ul");
    let getSidebarTitle = document.querySelector(".nav-sidebar span");
    let getSidebarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-sidebar a");

    if (toggleNavStatus === false){
        getSidebarUl.style.visibility = "visible";
        getSidebar.style.width = "272px";
        getSidebarTitle.style.opacity = "0.5";

        let arrayLength = getSidebarLinks.length();
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
            getSidebarLinks[i].style.opacity = "1";
          }

        toggleNavStatus = true;

    }

    else if (toggleNavStatus === true){
        getSidebar.style.width = "50px";
        getSidebarTitle.style.opacity = "0";

        let arrayLength = getSidebarLinks.length();
        for(let i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
            getSidebarLinks[i].style.opacity = "0";
        }

        getSidebarUl.style.visibility = "hidden";

        toggleNavStatus = false;

    }

}
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="XeroXipher" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>

    <title>End World</title>
</head>
    
    <body>
        
        <nav class="nav-main">
            <div class="btn-toggle-main" onclick="toggleNav()"></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></a></li>
                <li><a href="Cities">Cities</a></li>
                <li><a href="Forums">Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="AccountSettings">Account Settings</a></li>
                
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <aside>
             <nav class="nav-sidebar">
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Navigation</span></li>
                    <li><a href="Cities">Cities</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Forums">Forums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="AccountSettings">Account Settings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Logout">Logout</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
            </nav>
            
        </aside>
        
    
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  
</html>
```

**HTML Code**

I have a good understanding on how if, else works and I cannot figure out what isn't working.
It seems to run the if(false) correctly but not run else if(true);"

I have a good understanding on how if, else works and I cannot figure out what isn't working.
It seems to run the if(false) correctly but not run else if(true);"

Comment: There's not enough information in the question (various parts of the HTML seem to be missing) to know what's going on. Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Just edited to show all of my html, and this is the error I get in my console.log():

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'

(index):14 Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleNav is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):14:64)

```

Comment: Well if you're getting a syntax error, nothing is going to work. Fix that first.

Comment: Yes, I was putting a }; rather than } by itself, but some of the people here helped me realize my problem was using .length() rather than .length;

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug if you take a look at the console when trying to get the length.

```
let arrayLength = getSidebarLinks.length();
```

just remove the parentheses after the 'length'

```
let arrayLength = getSidebarLinks.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

> let arrayLength = getSidebarLinks.length();

`length` is not a method. So, no need of function call.

On removing the parantheses, the click me toggles elements visible and invisible.

Answer (score -1):

I hope this might helpful for your question. Instead of using if/else we can use javascript toggle. The thing your code not working was, one is tpe validation and elment will loss visiblity after first click.

```js
let toggleNav = function() {
    let getUl = document.querySelector(".toggle-ul");
    getUl.classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

```css
.btn-toggle-main{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.toggle-ul{
  display:none;
}
.toggle-ul.visible{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-main">
    <div class="btn-toggle-main" onclick="toggleNav()">Click Me</div>
       <ul class="toggle-ul visible">
            <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></a></li>
            <li><a href="Cities">Cities</a></li>
            <li><a href="Forums">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="AccountSettings">Account Settings</a></li>    
       </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: An answer without any explanation is not useful.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace

```
toggleNavStatus = true;
```

by

```
return true;
```

and

```
toggleNavStatus = false;
```

by

```
return false;
```

I'm not absolutely sure about it, but I guess as your function lacks a defined return value, it returns a standard value in the end that is assigned to *toggleNavStatus*, overwriting the value you set before.

Comment: No, this won't work. The code relies on that global variable, and returning a value from the event handler will have no effect on it.